# How does R divide these two matrices?

Tags: r, matrix

I select a row in a 3x5 matrix called mat1, mat1[1, ]. I want to divide another 3x5 matrix, mat2, by mat1[1, ]. I get the correct answer when I do mat1[1, ]/t(mat2). What I would like to know is how does R perform the division if I do not transpose mat2? I've tried to divide by row, by column, but the output does not match the one that R returns for mat1[1, ]/mat2. Can anyone please explain to me this? Thanks.

Example:

```
mat1 <- matrix(sample(1:50, 15, replace = T), byrow = T, ncol = 5)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(51:100, 15, replace = T), byrow = T, ncol = 5)
rowID <- c("grade 1", "grade 2", "grade 3", "grade 4", "grade 5", "grade 6")
colID <- c("school A", "school B", "school C", "school D", "school E")

rownames(mat1) <- rowID[1:3]
rownames(mat2) <- rowID[4:6]
colnames(mat1) <- colID
colnames(mat2) <- colID

> mat1
        school A school B school C school D school E
grade 1       46       30       25       16       39
grade 2       24       44        4       48       13
grade 3       27       40        2       43       17
> mat2
        school A school B school C school D school E
grade 4       80       74       71       81       83
grade 5       90       57       97       87       86
grade 6       68       71       96       87       63
```

Now I would like to express the number of grade 1 students as a ratio of students in grades 4,5,6 in the same school.

```
> ratiograde1 <- mat1[1,] / t(mat2)
> ratiograde1
           grade 4   grade 5   grade 6
school A 0.5750000 0.5111111 0.6764706
school B 0.4054054 0.5263158 0.4225352
school C 0.3521127 0.2577320 0.2604167
school D 0.1975309 0.1839080 0.1839080
school E 0.4698795 0.4534884 0.6190476
```

The above yields the correct ratio. However, I would like to understand how R derives the following set of values when I simply write mat1 / mat2 (instead of transposing mat2).

```
> mat1[1,] / mat2
         school A  school B  school C  school D  school E
grade 4 0.5750000 0.2162162 0.4225352 0.4814815 0.3012048
grade 5 0.3333333 0.6842105 0.2577320 0.5287356 0.1860465
grade 6 0.3676471 0.6478873 0.1666667 0.3448276 0.6190476
```

In the above, Which elements did R use in mat1[1, ] to divide by which elements in mat2 and in what order?

Comment: To divide `mat2` by `mat1` would be `mat2/mat1` not what you post. Please post an example of what you mean, I cannot understand how `mat1[1, ]/t(mat2)` relates to your stated goal of dividing a matrix by another of the same dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas I added an example. Hope it clarifies what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible since it draws a random sample and you did not set the random seed with `set.seed` first. Just create the data and use `dput` to create a version that is easy to paste into your question.

You are dividing a vector by a matrix since `mat1[1, ]` is a vector not a matrix. R processes the matrix in the denominator by columns so in your first example: 46/80, 30/74, 25/71, etc because in the transposed matrix, the first column is grade4 schools. When the matrix is not transposed, the first column is schoolA and you get 46/80 , 30/90 , 25/68 as the first column and then 16/74, 39/57, 46/71 as the first two rows in the second column since R recycles the values in the vector.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the explanation I was looking for! And also thanks for your first suggestion!